# Set layer variable when processing in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing

Does anyone know a way to set layer variables while processing a batch of layers in QGIS? Either through the graphical modeler or a processing script?

Comment: Could you give more details? What kind of setting do you mean? Do you mean "Input layer" by "layer variable"